# IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a class annotated with @Service. In that I have instance variable EntityManager annotated with PersistenceContext. I am getting IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Session/EntityManager is closed; exception

```
@Service
public class EntityService {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "contextConfig")
private EntityManager em;

public void updateEntity(Long entityId) {
        MyEntity entity = getEntity(entityId);
        entity.setLastModified(new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        em.merge(entity);
        return e;
    }

private MyEntity getEntity(Long entityId) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("from MyEntity t " +
            "where t.identifier = :entityId");
        q.setParameter("entityId", entityId);
        return (MyEntity) q.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

stack trace

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Session/EntityManager is closed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:575)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor789.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

This exception is intermittent not for all the calls. There is only one caller for this method. Appreciate your help, TIA

Comment: updateEntity method makes a call to getEntity which uses entity manager to fetch the entity from DB. After that, we use that entity in the entity manager for merge call. So here the 1st method updateEntity calls and uses entity manager again the same is used for merge. Is this allowed? right way to do?